# how to expand width of child elements according to parent width

Tags: css

I've the following set of li in my DOM. But all them have only a min-width and the width is set to according to the elements inside each li.

Demo : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kCRc3/14/)

parent css

```
#parent{
    width:1024px;
    height:90px;
    background-color:black
}
```

what I want is to expand the li elements width to fit the entire width of the parent element. How can I achieve this using css3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align: justify;` on the #header element.

Then stretch the content to take up 100% width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/kCRc3/19/)**

```
#header {
    text-align: justify;
}

#header li {
    display: inline-block;

}

#header:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: in your way, it comes to some what closer to what I expect! but if you can show me a way to make the li elements to grow and remove the spacing inbetween an li, that would be great

Comment: what align justify does is it spaces the items out equally to fit the total width. That's why there are spaces between the items. If you want, you could play with the margins between items to remove the space - but I think that if you change your parent width - then you'll have to change these as well. I updated the fiddle to improve this a bit.

Answer (score 2):

One way is `display: flex;`: http://jsfiddle.net/kCRc3/18/
Another is `display: table;` http://jsfiddle.net/kCRc3/24/

`display: table;` may seem more concise, but there are several quirks such as alignment of cell contents that you need to be aware of.

Comment: The problem with your method is that it's ideal for same width element. if you've taken a look at my fiddle, it shows each li has different width.. ny way to tackle that!

Comment: All you would have to do is add a `style="width: 100px;"` or `style="width: auto;"` attribute to each `<li>` with the correct width, or use selectors to do the same.

Comment: For the flexbox, if you want an `<li>` to not expand, then remove the `flex: 1` or if you want it to take a different amount of space, then you can use `flex: 3` etc. Refer to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: For the table, you may also want to play with `min-width` and `max-width`: http://jsfiddle.net/kCRc3/25/

Comment: Thank you Michael for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `display: [table, table-row, table-cell]` to expand elements in container.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/kCRc3/22/).

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: black;
    display: table;
}
#header {
    display: table-row;
}
.header-tile {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Adding 100% of width would make each li to take the entire width of the parent and makes it look like crap!

Comment: Then make your question more clear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think I've pretty much told the entire thing!

Comment: I understood it differently. Anyway, here is another solution you can use. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `width: 100%` to an element with `display: block;`, which is the case for any `li` element by default,  then it will expand to the size of its parent.

In your example that would be the `.header-tile`.

Note that `width` is already introduced in CSS1 and there's no need for any CSS2 or CSS3 rule or setting.

Comment: it doesn't work either. I've already attached inline-block and when I change it to block & use 100% width, the entire li set will show one under the other with a 100% width.

Comment: you asked for the element to grow to the width of its parent. This must result in the elements to stack. Do you mean the height maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it, you need to create new class-defining the remaining width i.e 
(parent width - all li width = remaining width) and add it to any of `<li class="header-tile newWidth">`i.e

```
.newWidth{
  width:100px; // this could be the remaining width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments i guess that you want all list items in combination fill the width of their parent, not each single one of them (so that there's no remaining space in the `ul`).

One way of doing this is to set their display behavior to table, like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SURzu/

If you don't have to fix the width of the `ul`, you could also set both `ul` and `li` tags to `display: inline-block;` to achieve this.